# Integration testing with Testcontainers + Quarkus + MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, docker, quarkus, testcontainers

Trying out testcontainers for integration testing. I am testing rest api endpoint. Here is the technology stack - 
quarkus, RESTEasy and mongodb-client

I am able to see MongoDB container is started successfully but getting exception. Exception: "com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket"

```
2020-04-26 15:13:18,330 INFO  [org.tes.doc.DockerClientProviderStrategy] (main) Loaded org.testcontainers.dockerclient.UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy from ~/.testcontainers.properties, will try it first
2020-04-26 15:13:19,109 INFO  [org.tes.doc.UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy] (main) Accessing docker with local Unix socket
2020-04-26 15:13:19,109 INFO  [org.tes.doc.DockerClientProviderStrategy] (main) Found Docker environment with local Unix socket (unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
2020-04-26 15:13:19,258 INFO  [org.tes.DockerClientFactory] (main) Docker host IP address is localhost
2020-04-26 15:13:19,305 INFO  [org.tes.DockerClientFactory] (main) Connected to docker: 
  Server Version: 19.03.8
  API Version: 1.40
  Operating System: Docker Desktop
  Total Memory: 3940 MB
2020-04-26 15:13:19,524 INFO  [org.tes.uti.RegistryAuthLocator] (main) Credential helper/store (docker-credential-desktop) does not have credentials for quay.io
2020-04-26 15:13:20,106 INFO  [org.tes.DockerClientFactory] (main) Ryuk started - will monitor and terminate Testcontainers containers on JVM exit
2020-04-26 15:13:20,107 INFO  [org.tes.DockerClientFactory] (main) Checking the system...
2020-04-26 15:13:20,107 INFO  [org.tes.DockerClientFactory] (main) ✔︎ Docker server version should be at least 1.6.0
2020-04-26 15:13:20,230 INFO  [org.tes.DockerClientFactory] (main) ✔︎ Docker environment should have more than 2GB free disk space
2020-04-26 15:13:20,291 INFO  [ .2]] (main) Creating container for image: mongo:4.2
2020-04-26 15:13:20,420 INFO  [ .2]] (main) Starting container with ID: d8d142bcdef8e2ebe9c09f171845deffcda503d47aa4893cd44e72d7067f0cdd
2020-04-26 15:13:20,756 INFO  [ .2]] (main) Container mongo:4.2 is starting: d8d142bcdef8e2ebe9c09f171845deffcda503d47aa4893cd44e72d7067f0cdd
2020-04-26 15:13:22,035 INFO  [ .2]] (main) Container mongo:4.2 started in PT3.721S
2020-04-26 15:13:24,390 INFO  [org.mon.dri.cluster] (main) Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2020-04-26 15:13:24,453 INFO  [org.mon.dri.cluster] (main) Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2020-04-26 15:13:24,453 INFO  [org.mon.dri.cluster] (cluster-ClusterId{value='5ea5dd542fb66c613dc74629', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017) Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:27017: com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketChannelStream.open(SocketChannelStream.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:714)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:122)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketChannelStream.initializeSocketChannel(SocketChannelStream.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketChannelStream.open(SocketChannelStream.java:60)
    ... 3 more
```

If I use docker run then my test case works properly.

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 --name mongodb mongo:4.2
```

using testcontainer as mentioned @ https://www.testcontainers.org/quickstart/junit_5_quickstart/

```
@Container
    static GenericContainer mongodb = new GenericContainer<>("mongo:4.2").withExposedPorts(27017);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't say for certain without seeing your test configuration, but I'm guessing that it works with `docker run` and not Testcontainers because `docker run` exposes a fixed port (always 27017) but Testcontainers will expose port `27017` *as a random port* (to avoid port conflicts on test machines).

To use Testcontainers with a Quarkus test, your tests must follow this flow:

1. Start containers. This is necessary because the random exposed port for MongoDB can only be known *after* the container has been started.
2. Obtain randomized ports from Testcontainers after containers are started, then set any test configuration properties that depend on container ports. For example:

   ```java
   static GenericContainer mongodb = new GenericContainer<>("mongo:4.2").withExposedPorts(27017);
   static {
     mongodb.start();
     System.setProperty("quarkus.mongodb.connection-string",
                        "mongodb://" + mongodb.getContainerIpAddress() + ":" + mongodb.getFirstMappedPort());
   }
   ```
3. Let Quarkus start. Since Quarkus does not support dynamic configuration, you must set the MongoDB port before Quarkus starts.

Answer (score 3):

As of version `2.0.0.Alpha1`, Quarkus will automatically start MongoDB via testcontainers in dev and test mode if no Mongo configuration has been supplied.

See [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/2.0.0.CR3/docs/src/main/asciidoc/mongodb.adoc#devservices-configuration-free-databases) for more information

Answer (score 2):

This solution works but Quakus provide a cleaner way of doing this check [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-test-resource). Just create a class implementing `QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager`

```
    public static class Initializer implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> start() {
            mongodb.start();
            return Maps.of("quarkus.mongodb.connection-string", "mongodb://" + mongodb.getContainerIpAddress() + ":" + mongodb.getFirstMappedPort());
        }


        @Override
        public void stop() {
            mongodb.stop();
        }
    }
```

Then annotate your test with
`@QuarkusTestResource(MyTestClass.Initializer.class)`

Answer (score 1):

Extending the @juan-rada answer with example (Quarkus + Mongo + Junit5)

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.groovy.util.Maps;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.testcontainers.containers.MongoDBContainer;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;
import io.quarkus.test.common.QuarkusTestResource;
import io.quarkus.test.common.QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;

@QuarkusTest
@Testcontainers
@QuarkusTestResource(FooIT.Initializer.class)
public class FooIT {

    public static class Initializer implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> start() {
            FooIT.mongoDBContainer.start();
            // the way to dynamically expose allocated port
            return Maps.of("quarkus.mongodb.connection-string", "mongodb://" + mongoDBContainer.getContainerIpAddress() + ":" + mongoDBContainer.getFirstMappedPort() + "/foo");
        }

        @Override
        public void stop() {
            FooIT.mongoDBContainer.stop();
        }
    }


    @Container
    public static final MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mongo:latest"));

    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
       ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your tests the `@QuarkusTestResource(MongoDBLifecycleManager.class)`.

And here we have the implementation of `MongoDBLifecycleManager`:

```
public class MongoDBLifecycleManager implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {

    private MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mongo:5.0.10"));

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {
        mongoDBContainer.start();

        return Map.of(
                "quarkus.mongodb.connection-string", mongoDBContainer.getConnectionString(),
                "quarkus.mongodb.database", "testDB");
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        mongoDBContainer.stop();
    }
}
```

It is important to notice that your tests will ignore what you defined in the `application.properties` as MongoDB connection parameters, and use what the method `start` returns:

```
Map.of("quarkus.mongodb.connection-string", mongoDBContainer.getConnectionString(),
       "quarkus.mongodb.database", "testDB");
```

You can have other MongoDB instances running in your local machine, with test containers you will run in a random port.

In your `pom.xml` you will need some like:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```