# Testcontainer doesn’t work with Kotlin and Quarkus - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongo:27017

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, quarkus, testcontainers

I am trying to create a simple todo application using **Quarkus**, **Kotlin**, **MongoDB** and **TestContainers**. I am using testcontainers to test my integration with mongodb. Unfortunately my test is not working like I expected. Here is my test case, I am not sure what goes wrong. I can see from the logs that the test container for mongodb is started and I am setting the replicaSetUrl in to the property.

```
@QuarkusTest
class TodoResourceIT {

    @Container
    private val mongoDbContainer: MongoDBContainer = MongoDBContainer("mongo:4.2").withExposedPorts(27017)

    init {
        mongoDbContainer.start()
        System.setProperty("quarkus.mongodb.connection-string", mongoDbContainer.replicaSetUrl)
    }
    @Test
    fun shouldReturn200OK() {
        given().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(Todo("1", "Find", "Find the letter F"))
            .`when`().post("/api/todos").then().statusCode(200)
    }
}
```

Here is my complete source code: https://github.com/faskan/todo-kotlin-quarkus

I have see a similar thread [Integration testing with Testcontainers + Quarkus + MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61447252/integration-testing-with-testcontainers-quarkus-mongodb). But the solution works only in Java. Here is my sample implementation using Java which works perfectly fine. https://github.com/faskan/todo-java-quarkus

The problem I'm facing now is with Kotlin.

Stacktrace:

```
INFO  [org.mon.dri.cluster] (cluster-ClusterId{value='60d34ff2ffb00164d8f60cbc', description='null'}-mongo:27017) Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongo:27017: com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongo
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:211)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:143)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mongo
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:800)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:886)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1507)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1366)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1300)
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:203)
```

Comment: That looks like a DNS problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which is your quarkus version?.

You can [QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-test-resource) to archieve that, I've already tested it with kotlin and work fine. [Here](https://github.com/javiertoja/stackoverflow/tree/main/kotlin-integration-tests-mongo) there is an example on how to do this

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was using a version lower than 2.0. I can upgrade my version to 2.0.0, but I couldn't find a documentation for the mongodb devservice. I was looking at https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/tree/main/docs/src/main/asciidoc. Can you please help with the link for the mongodb devservice documentation?

Comment: yes @FaisalKhan there not a lot of documentation, the devServices are just for developing mode, i have to update the response, but i will provide you with an example in my repo of a integration test with kotlin and mongo which will work in any quarkus version

Comment: @FaisalKhan check this repo https://github.com/javiertoja/stackoverflow/tree/main/kotlin-integration-tests-mongo, the important part is the class MockMongoDatabase, which implement the interface QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It works perfectly! But I am a bit confused on why the behavior differs between Java and Kotlin implementation. I was expecting kotlin 'init' block to work like Java 'static' block. Is there something wrong with my understanding.